# how do i redirect a table array to display its values in php

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

here is the code i am using for displaying my table ..

```
   $hfeed ="SELECT title, author , description ,price FROM items"; 
   $resfeed = $conn4->query($hfeed);
   echo   "<table>" ;
   echo "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Price</th></tr>";
   if ($resfeed->num_rows > 0) 
   {
   while($row = $resfeed->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
   echo "<tr> <td><a href='content.php'>". $row["title"]. "</a></td> <td>". $row["author"]. "</td> <td>" . $row["price"]. "</td> </tr>";
   }
   }
   else
   {
   echo "0 results";
   }
   echo "</table>";
```

what should i code for content.php to display the fields of a desired cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$_GET` in `a` tag:

`<a href='content.php?author=".$row["author"]."&title=".$row["title"]."'>".$row["title"]."</a>`

and in `content.php` file you handle the `$_GET` variables as such:

```
if(isset($_GET["author"])) { $author = $_GET["author"]; }
if(isset($_GET["title"])) { $title = $_GET["title"]; }

if(($author) && ($title)) {
    $sql = "SELECT column1,column2,columnN FROM items WHERE author=".$author." AND title=".$title;
    ..
    // do mysql query
    // show results.
}
```

Comment: its working ...but only for the first 2 items...here is the content.php   
   
     
    if(isset($_GET["author"])) { $author = $_GET["author"]; }
       if(isset($_GET["title"])) { $title = $_GET["title"]; }
    if(isset($_GET["description"])) { $description = $_GET["description"]; }
    
    if(($author) && ($title) && ($description))
    {
     $cfeed ="SELECT title, author,description FROM items WHERE title='$title' AND author='$author' AND description='$description'"; 
     $rescfeed = $conn5->query($cfeed);
     if ($rescfeed->num_rows > 0) 
  {
   echo $author;
 }
    }

Comment: it worked ...there was a problem with a database ..but that was taken care of..Thanx very much

Comment: @ronit Well, alright. Accept the answer if it helped you, so others can see aswell.

Answer (score 0):

try passing the values as parameters. maybe in a json format ? its up to you

Encode the row

```
json_encode($row)

href='content.php?parameters='.$row
```

then content.php should decode the parameters and u can use them.